# xml not mapping to java pojo

Tags: java, xml, spring-rest

I am trying to post xml to spring rest controller which has the below classes. XML is mapping correctly for Team object but its not mapping playerName in the Player object. playerName is always null. Can anyone please let me know what is wrong here.

My Player XML POJO

```
@XmlRootElement
@Entity(name = "player")
public class Player {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "player_id")
    private long player_id;

    @Column(unique=true , nullable = false)
    private String playerName;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "team_id")
    private Team team;

    public long getPlayer_id() {
        return player_id;
    }

    public void setPlayer_id(long player_id) {
        this.player_id = player_id;
    }


    public String getPlayerName() {
        return playerName;
    }

    public void setPlayerName(String playerName) {
        this.playerName = playerName;
    }

    public Team getTeam() {
        return team;
    }

    public void setTeam(Team team) {
        this.team = team;
    }


}
```

My Team XML POJO

```
@XmlRootElement
@Entity(name = "team")
public class Team {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "team_id")
    private long team_id;

    @Column(unique=true , nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "team")
    private List<Player> players;

    public long getTeam_id() {
        return team_id;
    }

    public void setTeam_id(long team_id) {
        this.team_id = team_id;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Player> getPlayers() {
        return players;
    }

    public void setPlayers(List<Player> players) {
        this.players = players;
    }


}
```

My Spring Rest Controller method

```
@RequestMapping(value="/team/", method = RequestMethod.POST , headers="Accept=application/xml")
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
    public void createTeam(@RequestBody Team team) throws Exception {
        for (Player player: team.getPlayers()){
            player.setTeam(team);
        }
        teamService.createTeam(team);
    }
```

My XML which i am posting to controller.

```
<team>
<name>GUj</name>
<players>
    <Player>
    <playerName>Raina</playerName> 
    </Player>
</players>
</team>
```

When i directly call player rest method with player xml then its working. below is the rest code for create player and player xml. it looks only mapping problem is child xml pojo in the parent xml pojo.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/player/", method = RequestMethod.POST , headers="Accept=application/xml")
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
    public void createPlayer(@RequestBody Player player) throws Exception {
        playerService.createPlayer(player);
    }
```

player xml

```
<player>
<playerName>Yuvraj</playerName> 
</player>
```

Attaching debug screen shot in which i can see playerName is null

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't the <Player> tag be <player> ?

Comment: Did you try configuring jacksonObjectMapper? this takes care of mapping.

Comment: @Jagrut i tried that case but no difference.

Comment: @Radhakrishna - I have almost done with this way only small piece of issue is stoping now. fixing this will help me to move forward

Comment: updated the question. When i directly call player rest method with player xml then its working. below is the rest code for create player and player xml. it looks only mapping problem is child xml pojo in the parent xml pojo.

Comment: updated with debug screenshot

Answer (score 1):

You need to define `XmlElement` on the Players list.

```
@XmlElement(name="players")
public List<Player> getPlayers() {
    return players;
}
```

Hope this helps!